# How do I know when polymer dart is completely initialized?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

The following code works in Dartium but throws an exception in recent Firefox and Edge:

```
initPolymer().then((Zone z) {
    (document.getElementById("fooDialog") as PolymerElement)
                .set("opened", true);
});
```

Where `fooDialog` is custom polymer element in the body of the document. The message from the exception:

```
Casting value of type HtmlElement to incompatible type PolymerElement
```

The problem disappears when I rewrite it to:

```
initPolymer().then((Zone z) {
    new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        (document.getElementById("fooDialog") as PolymerElement)
                .set("opened", true);
    });
});
```

So I gues that I call `set` to early. How do I know when polymer is completely initialized in recent rc of dart polymer (dart sdk 1.15.0, polymer 1.0.0-rc.16)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce. See also https://github.com/bwu-dart-playground/polymer1/blob/269a9746e6c0cd5ba6ceec81b3bb4c3126135be1/so36384493_wait_for_polymer_initialized/web/index.dart#L10-L10. There might be some issue with script tags that result in a weird timing issue

Comment: To build your example on Windows I had to change the dependencies to `polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.16`, `polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.8`, `reflectable: ^0.5.1`, `web_components: ^0.12.0` (if I don't change them I was getting `Invalid argument(s): Illegal character in path` during build).  After that I can reproduce the issue in FF and Edge.

Comment: Ok, I'll check again.

Comment: I tried with Iceweasel 38.6.1 and Microsoft Edge 34.14295.1000.0 and can't reproduce. The version constraints you posted are not very helpful. `^1.0.0-rc.8` could still fetch `1.0.0-rc.16`. I would need the versions actually fetched by `pub upgrade`. Either run `pub upgrade` and get the listed versions from the output or check in `pubspec.lock`. It might be worth trying to delete the `.pub` directory and try again.

Comment: I have exactly: `1.0.0-rc.16`, `polymer_elements 1.0.0-rc.8`, `reflectable 0.5.2` and `web_components 0.12.3` as reported by `pub upgrade`, browsers: Firefox 45.0.2 and Edge 25.10586. I also tried to remove `.pub` but it didn't change anything. It really looks like some timing issue.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. Maybe Windows related (I'm on Linux). You could try a bug report in the https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart repo